# What concepts do I need to solve this nonlinear problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Problem Details:**

Let $L$ be a linear operator and $N(u)$ be a nonlinear function of $u$. Consider the IVP for the following nonlinear PDE:

$$\partial_{t}u + L(u) = N(u)$$

defined on $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and subject to $u(x,0) = f(x)$ for $f(x)$ smooth and decaying at $x \pm\infty$.

**Problem Statement:**

Suppose $u(x,t)$ is a function such that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \geq 0$ $$u(x,t) = f(x) + \int_{0}^{t} (-L(u(x,t')) + N(u(x,t'))dt'$$

Show that $u$ solves the initial value problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the function $u(x,t)$ solves the initial value problem, you need to calculate $\partial_t(u)$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus and then show the result is $N(u) -L(u)$.  Also show the initial condition is satisfied.